# Including header files in gcc cygwin to windows drive:root

Tags: windows, gcc, build, cygwin, include-path

The company I am working for is in the process of moving its development from borland in windows to gcc in unix.

Normally we build by using windows "subst" of a project to a specific drive. This means that all our include paths are relative to the drive root eq. Include < model\normal\xx.h >

I am trying to build a project using the i686-pc-mingw32-gcc compiler through cygwin in windows. But I am unable to include the large amount of header files.

I have tried to use "mount", make symbolic links "ln -s" and even move the file to C:\cygwin. But the path still needs < \model\normal\xx.h > and not < model\normal\xx.h > as it currently is .

I would really like not to change the path in all my header files since the program still should be able to work in the old build environment.

Hope some one out there was a solution

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just do the following, assuming "model" is in "/" (a horrible place for it to be, but that's up to you):

gcc -I /

You can also set the environment variables CPATH or C_INCLUDE_PATH, i.e.:

export CPATH=/
or
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/

or for C++
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/